# Add Borders to word from vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I have merged 3 word documents into one in Word Interop Library

```
Dim wrdApp As New Word.Application
Dim docNew As Word.Document
docNew = wrdApp.Documents.Add        
docNew.Range.InsertFile(b)
myRange = docNew.Paragraphs(docNew.Paragraphs.Count).Range
myRange.InsertParagraph()

myRange.InsertFile(c)
myRange = docNew.Paragraphs(docNew.Paragraphs.Count).Range
myRange.InsertParagraph()

myRange.InsertFile(d)
myRange = docNew.Paragraphs(docNew.Paragraphs.Count).Range
myRange.InsertParagraph()
```

Now i wanted to add borders, font. I have tried following code for margin :

```
docNew.PageSetup.TopMargin = 50
docNew.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 50
docNew.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 50
docNew.PageSetup.RightMargin = 50
```

How we can do for Borders and Font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the **LineStyle** property for a section applies a page border around the pages in the section.

This is from [Border.LineStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.border.linestyle%28v=office.14%29.aspx)